# How to append current path ending to href in body link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to this site, and I know almost nothing about programming, so this question may have a simple answer.
I want to have links in my site that are able to grab a part of the current URL address to complete the href and send me to the desired webpage.
For example, let’s say that the webpage in my site I am viewing is:
https://www.example.com/notes/note-1
And then I have links in the same page like these ones:
https://www.example.com/editor1
https://www.example.com/editor2
Is there a way (java or jquery) that I can grab the last part of the path name (/note-1) to dynamically add it to my html links so the new addresses become?:
https://www.example.com/editor1/note-1
https://www.example.com/editor2/note-1
Now, I don’t need a code that appends “note-1” to the href, but that appends the ending of the current path—whatever it maybe (“/note-2, /note-3, etc.) to the href.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement it like so:

```
const idx = location.href.lastIndexOf('/');
const lastPart = idx !== -1 ? location.href.slice(idx + 1): "";
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a=>a.href+=lastPart);
```

Comment: @Moises No problem.